# Is it possible to animate the application of -webkit-tap-highlight in iOS Web?

Tags: ios, css, webkit, mobile-webkit

I am trying to animate the application of `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` on links in iOS. Currently it is applied instantly. I am wondering if there is a way to apply a CSS transition to this?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in a word: **No.**

You can refer to the official [W3C Working Draft regarding CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-) for a complete list of supported animatable properties.